# index in a tuple of a dictionaries python

Tags: python, indexing

I have a tuple which its elements are dictionaries. i.e.

```
tuple=({"code":101,"assignment":'math',"credits":2},
       {"code":102,"assignment":'physics',"credits":3},
       {"code":103,"assignment":'chemistry',"credits":2},
       {"code":104,"assignment":'biology',"credits":5},
       {"code":105,"assignment":'science',"credits":1}
```

Then I want to check how many credits each student has, but first I would like to have a list the index where each code is

```
student1=[101,103]
student2=[102,104,105]
```

So I would like have

```
student1list=[1,3]
student1credits=4
student2list=[2,4,5]
student2credits=9
```

I can get those credits with 2 for like this

```
s1=[]
for i in range(len(student1)) :
  for j in range(len(tuple)) :
    if  student1[i]==tuple[j]['code'] :
      s1.append(tuple[j]['credits'])

student1credits=0
for k in range(len(s1)):
  student1credits=student1credits+s1[k]

print(student1credits)
```

But no idea of how to get the indexes

Comment: Do not use `tuple` as a variable name as it is a builtin in the python language and overwriting its value will cause problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with `enumerate`.

```py
tuple_credits = ({"code":101,"assignment":'math',"credits":2},{"code":102,"assignment":'physics',"credits":3},{"code":103,"assignment":'chemistry',"credits":2},{"code":104,"assignment":'biology',"credits":5},{"code":105,"assignment":'science',"credits":1})

code_to_idx = {x['code']: i for i, x in enumerate(tuple_credits)}

def idx_and_credits(student):
    idx = [code_to_idx[c] for c in student]
    cred = sum(tuple_credits[i]['credits'] for i in idx)
    return idx, cred

student1list, student1credits = idx_and_credits([101, 103])
student2list, student2credits = idx_and_credits([101, 103, 101, 105])

print(student1list, student1credits) # [0, 2] 4
print(student2list, student2credits) # [0, 2, 0, 4] 7
```

In Python, index starts with 0, so `student1list` would be `[0, 2]` instead of `[1, 3]`. Also I renamed `tuple` to `tuple_credits`, as `tuple` is a built-in function.

Comment: Hey, actually this is almost what I need, but what if I had a code that was twice in the student list? And I would like to have both in the student list and the total in student credits?

Comment: @SebasRoldan I am sorry I don't understand your request.

Comment: I know in this example it doesn't fit, but lets say
student = [101, 103,101,105]
then studentlist =[0,2,0,4] and
studentcredits=7

Comment: Ah now I understand what you mean. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1):

This feels like something where pandas would help out a lot.

```py
import pandas as pd

tuple=({"code":101,"assignment":'math',"credits":2},
{"code":102,"assignment":'physics',"credits":3},
{"code":103,"assignment":'chemistry',"credits":2},
{"code":104,"assignment":'biology',"credits":5},
{"code":105,"assignment":'science',"credits":1})

my_data = pd.DataFrame(tuple)

my_data.head()
```

|  | code | assignment | credits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | math | 2 |
| 1 | 102 | physics | 3 |
| 2 | 103 | chemistry | 2 |
| 3 | 104 | biology | 5 |
| 4 | 105 | science | 1 |

#### Look up the codes for a student

```py
student1=[101,103]
keep = my_data.code.isin(student1)
my_data[keep]
```

|  | code | assignment | credits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | math | 2 |
| 2 | 103 | chemistry | 2 |

#### Get just the index

```py
student1=[101,103]
keep = my_data.code.isin(student1)
my_data[keep].index.values
```

> array([0, 2], dtype=int64)

ps: Sorry, these index start at 0 instead of 1...hope that is ok. :)

### An Extension...

Let's store our student-class relationship in pandas too, and do the look up/sum of credits.

```py
student_class_relationships = pd.DataFrame(
    {'student_id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
     'code': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105]}
)

my_data \
    .merge(student_class_relationships, on='code') \
    .groupby('student_id') \
    .agg({'credits': 'sum'})
```

| student_id | credits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 8 |

Comment: You can pass an `index` to the data frame like so `pd.DataFrame(tuple, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=len(tuple), name='index'))` if they really want a 1 based index